# problem on a trapezoid having intersection of diagonals

Tags: geometry

This problem is hard for me. Can anyone help me? Thank you in advance.

Let ABCD be a trapezoid with the measure of base AB twice that of base DC, and let E be the point of intersection of diagonals. If the measure of diagonal AC is 11, then that of segment EC is equal to?

[image]

Comment: triangle AEB is similar to the triangle CDE.

Answer (score 1):

triangles ABE and CDE are similar, hence: $\frac{AB}{DC}=\frac{AE}{CE}=2$ and AE+EC=11. Hence, EC=$11/3$.

Comment: Thanks. I think that my brain did not work.